# Convert List Elements with Tags and nest text

Tags: xml, xslt

I try to convert my List Element from html to xml. The problem is that the List Element contains paragraphs elements and sometimes the first note is Text without any element.
I will copy the paragraphs with apply-templates command and nest the first note if it is text without and paragraph element into a p tag.

**Example code I will convert:**

```
<li>Text1 <p>Text2</p></li>
```

**This is how the result should look like. The first text note is nested in p tag**

```
<li><p>Text1</p><p>Text2</p></li>
```

**My xls template I currently use but**

```
<xsl:template match="li">
  <li>
    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
  </li> 
</xsl:template>
```

Does anyone here have an idea or best a code sample

thanks

Comment: Your input has 2 text nodes, the output has 3. What is the logic behind that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to add another template:

```
<xsl:template match="li/text()">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p> 
</xsl:template>
```

in addition to the *identity transform* template and the template shown in your question (which BTW can be removed, as the *identity transform* template will perform the same action as default).

Comment: Thank you 
Now each text node is encapsulated below li in a day p
I've just noticed that also may contain an inline tag like a, span or img.
Is there a possibility to copy these elements into the p tag.

**This is my source code**
 <li>
  Text1<soanTestx</span>Test<img src=""><a>text</a>
  <p>Text2</p>
 </li>

**This is how it should look like**
 <li>
  <p>Text1<soanTestx</span>Test<img src=""><a>text</a></p>
  <p>Text2</p>
 </li>

Is there a way to copy these inline element?

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Either add this to your question or ask a new one.